# angular/python - browser caching issue on each change

Tags: python, angularjs, angular, caching, browser-cache

working on a website built with python and angular but after every single change I need to hard reset browser to see it. I see this is a problem in general so what's the best approach for caching js and css resources ? right now I dont care if each file will be called on every single page if there is no other option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force browser to reload cached CSS/JS files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/how-to-force-browser-to-reload-cached-css-js-files)

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to development time? If so, this can often be set in the browser. Which browser are you using? For Chrome:

1. Open the developer tools.
2. Select the network tab.
3. Check the `Disable cache` checkbox

Comment: we have 150 testers I can not tell them to do the same

Comment: That is why I was asking whether you were referring to development time. You didn't mention testers in your post.

Answer (score 1):

For testing/deployment, consider building the files with a unique number attached to them so that the browser sees them as new files.

The easiest way to perform these builds is to use the angular CLI build process: github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build.

The screenshot below is from John Papa's excellent `Angular CLI` course on Pluralsight.

[image]